# Make an array from list where first element of the array is the first element in list

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures

I am very new to ruby so excuse me if this is a basic question.

I have a list that looks like this:

```
    [name, max, john, raj, sam]
```

And i want to make a new array that will look like this:

```
    [[name, max], [name, john], [name, raj], [name, sam]]
```

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
    row.xpath('td').each_with_index do |cell, index|
     if index == 0
      tarray['name'] << cell.text
     else
      tarray['values'] << cell.text
    end
```

I know i am doing it wrong because when i have ['name'] it will not be logically possible to have ['values']
Please advice me on how i can achieve this using the best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-product) is better, but you can also use [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
ary = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

([ary.first]*(ary.size-1)).zip ary[1..]
#=> [[:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:a, :d]]
```

Or also:

```
ary.then { |a, *rest| ([a] * rest.size).zip rest }
```

But yes, product is cleaner:

```
ary.then { |a, *rest| [a].product rest }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take the first value (`:name`) and get its product with every remaning element by using [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
array = [:name, :max, :john, :raj, :sam]
p [array[0]].product(array[1..-1])
# [[:name, :max], [:name, :john], [:name, :raj], [:name, :sam]]
```